# Cannot load ExtJS 5 inside spring web app

Tags: spring, extjs, web-applications

i have problems to load my application. I created a Spring Web application and using Sencha cmd, i created an app inside webapp/resources folder.

This is my view.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LOGIN</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="<c:url value="/resources/apps/BetsTrackerAuth/ext/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css"/>">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/apps/BetsTrackerAuth/ext/build/ext-all.js"/>"</script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/apps/BetsTrackerAuth/ext/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"/>"</script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/resources/apps/BetsTrackerAuth/app.js"/>" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    LOGIN Hello world!  
</h1>
<P>  The time on the server is ${serverTime}. </P>
</body>
</html>
```

And my error is:

```
GET http://localhost:8084/app/app/Application.js?_dc=1433427933321 404 (Not Found)
```

What's wrong in my view?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say for sure without seeing your `app.js` file, but I would guess it is trying to load various dependencies -- namely `Application.js`.

Looking at the URL, I can see two levels of `/app/`, which tells me it's probably looking in the wrong place (for whatever reason).

Try setting the Ext.Loader paths before you load `app.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true,
  paths: {
      'MyApp': 'path/to/app'
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I only generate an application with sencha cmd. My app.js is the original file.